# Convert NSData to NSString using NSUTF8StringEncoding is not working for special character

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, nsstring

I want to parse a CSV file to create a String.

I fetch the data with the Dropbox API. Let's say my CSV file contains a simple word: "**école**". When I try to create a String I get the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

My code:

```
client.files.download(path: "/\(selectedFile)", destination: destination).response { response, error in
    if let (_, url) = response {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

        print("data: \(data!)")

        let myString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

        let csv = CSwiftV(String: myString)        
    } else {
        print(error!)
    }
}
```

The `print("data: \(data!)")` works well, it prints a bunch of hexadecimal. So I understand my data are not nil (right?).

If my CSV file contains the word "**ecole**" instead of "**école**" it works perfectly. But as far as I know, UTF-8 encoding should support special character no?

Comment: "Every time you use force unwrap a kitty die", use `guard` or `if` instead, in order to treat optional values

Comment: That means that the file uses some other encoding, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your data is encoded in other code rather `NSUTF8StringEncoding` decode it with the same encoding
For Example

```
let string = "école"
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let myString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String //This is OK

let string = "école"
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)
let myString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String // This will not work and myString will be nil
```

And please try to avoid force Unwrap (!) even if you are sure that you have data there, because you can have a crash next time you use !

I would do it like this instead:

```
 guard let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
       let myString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
 print("something terrible happened treat error")
}
 let csv = CSwiftV(String: String(myString))
```